# Questions asking for resources - On or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Inspired by this question:

> https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/451/resources-for-lost-wax-casting

Should we make requests for resources off topic here?

Answer (score 5):

#### Off Topic

There are several general issues with these questions and they should be off-topic.

Firstly, they fall into the "[avoid subjective questions](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" rule number one "avoid questions where every answer is equally valid". There are likely dozens or even hundreds of books out there to help this user, so every book would be an answer and that's too much. The OP can find this information by visiting a library or doing some research on the web.

They also are a corollary to the "[your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)" issue of link-only answers. Yes, the question is specifically asking to be linked somewhere else (either another website or a book title) but that circumvents the main point of our site... we are here to **be a resource**, not to point you to them. These lists can become out of date quickly and won't necessarily have the longevity we should hope for here.

Thus, the questions are often too broad.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

In this case, the OP **knows** that there are entire books written on the subject... but we're not here to tell you to go read a book, we're here to help you with the specific questions you have about your craft. Plus, without knowing specifically what problem you are trying to solve, we can not possibly guarantee that the list of resources will solve that problem.

Comment: Resources should be supplements to answers not the core focus. Requests for them can _maybe_ be directed to chat but should be closed. We have seen a couple already like this so a close reason geared to concept will likely be helpful. _without knowing specifically what problem you are trying to solve_ The OP can always narrow down if they want to get specific. Comments / Close reason should reflect that so as to not present a hard stop. Then we can maybe reopen. The example question is too broad.

Comment: Perhaps a bold header specifying off topic, since that seems to be your intent?

Comment: @CreationEdge Meh... fine. I think it's a bit heavy-handed format wise but... ok.

Comment: Up to you. Might encourage voting, though.

Comment: I  am a large fan of the header markup. I think it gives of clear intent and is better that tl;dr in some cases. Some people don't know the acronym.