# Are service inquires off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I figured I would ask here to see if anyone had experience with any services, but not sure if service recommendations are off-topic.

From what I see off-topic has a lot to do with opinions, and even though, in my case, the answer could be an opinion, I would assume there are facts that could be constructed into a good answer to help others as well.

I saw this question [Questions asking for resources - On or off topic?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183/questions-asking-for-resources-on-or-off-topic)

But seems to have to do with something different from what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, soliciting recommendations for services or broad reviews of such services are not within the scope of most Stack Exchange sites.

Incidentally, I should mention that this isn't necessarily the same thing as a **product search** where folks are trying to figure out how to solve a problem that just *happens* to involve a purchase. We do not host brand and best-product reviews/recommendations, but I often see folks closing legitimate product/tool questions by citing the moratorium on [Shopping Recommendations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Asking about product and solution searches was never what was actually meant in that blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  've seen a lot of questions on products in Stack Overflow, and other programming related stacks a lot, but not sure how often they are labeled as "off topic."  I'm not really looking for "best product reviews," but more if anyone has experience with any of these companies, because I'm not really sure what things should cost, and all that when it comes to getting some metal cutting done.  I appreciate your answer, thank you.

Comment: @XaolingBao You are certainly welcome to ask around in our chat rooms.They're are much more free-form with conversations than our Q&A.

Comment: @XaolingBao Once an answer is up-voted, the post cannot be removed by the author. Unless there is an exceptional reason to remove it, we prefer to keep this content available for folks who may also benefit from this information (I'm sure others have wondered the same thing).

Comment: Yeah, it's really more about services, and not my service.  I'm going to be deleting these 2 commments, so if you want to delete your last one, feel free.  Want to keep everything on topic... Will be editing question to fit the needs more, and less about what I needed.