# Is this "how do I learn this" question off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

[Best resources to learn origami art immediately?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/best-resources-to-learn-origami-art-immediately)

The question is subjective, vague and at the end of the day asking after how to learn an entire art form. What kind of origami style are they going for as there are several? People learn in different ways: that fact allowed that question to attract many different plausible answers. It usually boils down to practice anyway.

I would think very few people become instant artists.

If this question was new I would have voiced these concerns to the OP, but it's already got votes and answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think in part it is poorly phrased -- at least, I hope nobody would expect to be an expert "immediately" without any practice :)

We have actually already determined that [asking for resources is off-topic](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183/30). Even aside from the urgency, "I want to learn how to..." questions are too broad for us to reasonably answer. There are in-person classes, books, videos, forums... even "ask your friend who's doing all that work" is a valid answer! And that same answer can work whether we're talking about origami, knitting, oil painting, sketching anime...

It's just not a style of question that we can answer, and therefore should be closed. (And I'm closing your specific example now that I've seen it; I apparently missed it before!)